# PySpark: forward fill dataframe column with last non-null value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataset of sensor readings for individual devices. Some sensor readings are very frequent (every 1s) while others are less frequent and still others are available only when a change is detected. I've gotten all the readings into the same dataframe via pivot based on device id and timestamp, but this leaves me with a sparsely populated dataset and lots of missing values. I want to replace these nulls with the last non-null value for any given device. Effectively the data is continuous so it can't be sessionized, and partitioning based on device would result in sets way too large to fit in memory on my cluster.

Some psedudocode for what I've got at the moment:

```
df = spark.read.format("delta").load("gs://sensor-data")

device_window = Window.partitionBy('DeviceId')\
           .orderBy('EventTimeUTC')\

filled_ambient_temp = last('ambient_temp', ignorenulls=True).over(device_window)
filled_df = df.withColumn(col=filled_ambient_temp, colName="AmbientTemp").drop("ambient_temp")
```

This will work, but only if I add a filter based on date to the initial df to reduce the amount of data in each partition. Is there a better way?

Comment: Take a look here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.lag.html

Comment: Thanks! Lag won't work for me though because the offset can't be known ahead of time. Last would work, but again I'm concerned about exceeding the memory available on an executor and crashing out.

Comment: If you could post some code it would help. "replace these nulls with the last non-null value " does sound like something that most front-ends (Power BI, Tableu, ...) would support, so if that's the only reason then reconsider.